# My answer which I thought was an answer turned out not being an answer

Tags: discussion, answers, not-an-answer, specific-answer

I come just now from [Why is an integer array search loop slower in C++ than Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56209900/56210331#56210331).

When I first answered, I was convinced that compiling with optimization and removing the output operation from OP's C++ code would have made C++ perform better than the Java equivalent. I didn't check, as OznOg pointed out, and it's my fault. Then I did the actual tests, and realized that applying what I was saying still made C++ perform worse than Java.

But still the things I pointed out play a role in making C++'s version performance closer to the Java equivalent, and explain a deep flaw in OP's code used doing the comparison. All that won't fit in a comment, and if split in different messages would make the comment section messy.

How should I proceed?

- Should I leave my close-to-an-answer-but-not-an-answer "answer" there until someone with the actual answer shows up?
- Should I leave it there even after an answer arrives, to let future readers still access the notes about what made OP's test flawed?
- Should I remove my answer?

Comment: You need to leave the answer for now, it adequately proves that there's something unusual going on. The question needs to be voted back up to give it a chance to get answered.  It is going to need somebody that knows the Hotspot compiler well to explain the unusually fast Java result.  I retagged to [visual-c++] to lower the odds for more existential angst votes.

Comment: @HansPassant In that case, wouldn't it be more effective to edit the evidence from the answer into the question, while framing it in the way you suggest? (That is roughly what would have happened if the OP there had accepted the suggestions from the comments and fixed the benchmark themselves.)

Comment: By the way, I have retracted my answer that suggested deletion, partly due to Hans' comment, and partly because the timeline of the question is more complicated than I had realised at first (the OP originally didn't compile with optimisations, and updated their benchmark results later on).

Answer (score 27, accepted):

In this particular case, since

- the solution is apparently too hard to work out at once but your post is a significant step towards it
- you clearly stated that this is not a complete answer but it is a step towards it

this can be left as is -- until a real answer appears, at least.

[MathOverflow uses this approach when dealing with open problems](https://mathoverflow.net/help/on-topic).